# Wavelet transform, scalogram, detail and approximation coefficients

Tags: pywavelets

I understand tha the wavelet transform is about computing the coefficients to assign to scaled and translated versions of the chosen mother wavelet. The coefficients measure the correlation between the signal and shifted/scaled wavelet. That said, I know that the CWT is used to compute the scalogram while the DWT is used for other tasks (denoising and decomposition) and is implemented as a bank of low-pass and high pass filters...there is also a father wavelet, beside the mother wavelet, involved in the DWT...I don't think the CWT involves a father wavelet...Both the CWT and the DWT are discrete transforms where the scale and translation parameters are discretized in different ways...

I am confused about the difference between the CWT and the DWT. In the case of the DWT, are all the outputs from the low-pass and high-pass filters in the filter bank simply different low frequency and high frequency versions of the original input time-signal x(t)? The filter output signals are called approximation and detail coefficients cA and cD...I guess cA and cD are not time signals, correct? Can we add all the filters outputs, cA and CD, to get the original signal x(t)?

I get some mother wavelets can form orthogonal sets, some non-orthogonal sets, and some biorthogonal sets...

Thank you!

Comment: Have you had a look at the [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_wavelet_transform#Definition)?

Comment: I have and I sort of follow the idea of various cascaded filters. I guess I am stuck thinking that wavelets are to obtain a scalogram F(w,t) showing which frequencies exist at which time. I am not sure about the meaning of the approximation and detail coefficients

Comment: In essence, at each stage, detail coefficients are the outputs of the high pass filter, and approximations of the low pass filter. These are time-domain signals.

Comment: The low pass filters are related to the father wavelet and the high pass filters to the mother wavelet. in what way? Why don't we have father wavelets in the CWT?

Comment: I think you need to learn a little more about the basics, the questions you are asking have well documented answers in any wavelet theory book or online resources. Once you have a good understanding of these basics I'm sure some more focused questions will arise, and we'll be glad to answer. The answer to "what is the difference between the CWT and DWT" can and should be found elsewhere IMO, but maybe someone else here will oblige ;)